# Where is the MySQLdb module real file path?

Tags: python, python-module, pymysql

```
In [29]: import MySQLdb
In [31]:  MySQLdb
Out[31]: <module 'pymysql' from 'G:\\QGB\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\__init__.py'>
```

Why doesn't MySQLdb exist and why can I import it?

I wonder why there is no "MySQLdb" python file or dir in the sys.path.  How should I import "MySQLdb" in Python?

in Django VERSION = (2, 1, 1, 'final', 0),
\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py   line 15.

```
 import MySQLdb as Database
```

Comment: It exists. You imported it. What troubles you? Try using it.

Comment: i wonder why there is not a "MySQLdb" python file or dir in the sys.path.  how python interpreter can import "MySQLdb"  ?

Comment: I guess you have your own MySQLdb but python looks for it in the default location first. Try changing the name or insert the path before the default path

Comment: no......   in django VERSION = (2, 1, 1, 'final', 0),  \Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py   line 15.             import MySQLdb as Database

Answer (score 1):

A `MySQLdb` import may come from a different package (installed with `pip install mysqlclient`).

The distribution `pymysql` is intended to be used as a drop-in replacement for [the original project](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html), but as a courtesy they did not take the same import name. Instead, [they provide a convenience function](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/v0.9.2/pymysql/__init__.py#L120-L125) which squats the same name in `sys.modules`. This way, `import MySQLdb` will not attempt to traverse `sys.path` again, but instead re-use the already-loaded `pymysql` module:

```
>>> import pymysql
>>> pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb??
Signature: pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
Source:   
def install_as_MySQLdb():
    """
    After this function is called, any application that imports MySQLdb or
    _mysql will unwittingly actually use pymysql.
    """
    sys.modules["MySQLdb"] = sys.modules["_mysql"] = sys.modules["pymysql"]
File:      ~/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py
Type:      function
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason is :

in your project somewhere

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```